# Unable to SSH with shell into NAS: "error: openpty: Invalid argument"

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, shell, network-attached-storage

I have a WD MyBook WorldEdition II (White Light) NAS here. This essentially is a `ARM926EJ-S` with two SATA drives attached. For quite some time, I was running Debian 6.0 Squeeze on it. Now I recently updated to Debian 7.0 Wheezy with a custom step in the upgrade process, which I describe next.

Unfortunately, the system has to run on kernel version 2.6.24. This is, because WD made some patches to the kernel and has not updated it for a while. I am (currently) not able to apply these patches to a newer kernel version. As a result, I was not able to update `libc` within `apt-get dist-upgrade`. The `libc` of Wheezy requires minimum kernel of 2.6.26. However, I cross-compiled the `libc` w.r.t. kernel 2.6.24. This was advertised at some forum and claimed to work. Eventually after manually upgrading `libc`, `apt-get dist-upgrade` successfully continued.

However, after rebooting I am unable to open a shell via SSH. Instead, I get the following error message:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
[...]
stdin: is not a tty
```

I can execute commands though.

After investigating a bit more, I found out, that `/var/log/auth.log` contains:

```
sshd[4161]: error: openpty: Invalid argument
sshd[4161]: error: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc failed
```

For `openpty: Invalid argument` I have found only minimal information, e.g. [this forum post](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/2447/), where the user eventually re-installed the SSH server.

Some more information:

- `mount` shows, that `/dev/pts` is mounted.
- `/dev/pts` however is empty (which I think is normal, if no-one is logged in).
- Downgrading `openssh-server` to the squeeze version did not help.

So, right now I am at the end of my knowledge. It would be great to have a way to debug which `Invalid argument` is actually passed to `openpty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to solve this by re-compiling `libc` once more. I assume it must have been something in the toolchain, as I this time used a `chroot` being especially set to `wheezy`.